# functions in opencv programming

Tags: opencv

I am a newbie to opencv and am trying to implement shape context descriptor outlined in the slide http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/courses/spring2008/slides/ShapeContexts425.pdf

I found the edge points on the shape using canny edge detector for the first part of step 1. Then I need to calculate the Euclidean distance on each edge point to the other ones. Rather than using for-loops to find the distance between each and every point, is there any opencv function that can do this step more efficiently?

Comment: How OpenCV is supposed to find distances between all the pairs more efficiently, than simply looping between them?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I saw people try thresholding with a simple statement as: Mat img_bw = im_gray > 128;  So I thought there might be some matrix function to access the values easier than indexing in opencv?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's because i'm still trying to test it out. Thanks for replying my question! =D

Answer (score 0):

Finding all pairwise distances between the set of points is not a standard operation and I don't think you will find something similar in OpenCV. And it is very easy to compute by hand. Given two points `a` and `b`, you can calculate distance between them as `cv::norm(a - b)`, as described [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188/calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point/).

You might want to utilize the [`matchShapes`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes) function. However, it operates with image moments, not with shape descriptor you mentioned.